# regex email : extract domain with multiple dot

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this email addresses john@domain.com.ch and also john@domain.org. I'm using this regex pattern :

```
$pattern="(?ms)@(.*?)\."
```

And only managed to extract 'domain' for john@domain.org but not john@domain.com.ch. Please help me how to get 'domain' from both of email addresses. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the option of using a split on @ and simply take the second part?

Comment: Maybe `(?ms)@(.*?)(?:\s|$)`? This capture everything after the `@` until a whitespace or the end of the string.

Comment: tried. but result only produced 'domain' for .org.thx

Answer (score 2):

There are flaws with this if there are other @ signs in your text (like a twitter handle) but keeping it simple you could just match everything after the @ until the first space. Consider the following bacon ipsum

> Bacon ipsum dolor amet ham hock shoulder pastrami ham andouille
>   fatback **john@domain.com.ch** frankfurter ribeye pork. Picanha pig
>   frankfurter, ground round shank prosciutto doner flank. Alcatra doner
>   chicken pork chop shoulder, fatback turkey sausage flank picanha.
>   **john@domain.org**
>
> Meatloaf short loin pancetta turkey.
>
> Rump sirloin meatball, shoulder @ ground round biltong beef ribs
>   kielbasa spare ribs chicken capicola flank drumstick. Jowl cow short
>   loin pastrami biltong filet mignon rump pork chop capicola alcatra.

Running the regex `@([^\s]+)` would get the results (from the first capture group)

```
domain.com.ch
domain.org
```

If the above text was a raw string in the variable `$text` then the following line would generate

```
$text | Select-String "@([^\s]+)" -AllMatches | Select-Object -Expand matches | Select-Object -Expand Value
```

Output on console

```
@domain.com.ch
@domain.org
```

You could use look behinds to omit the @ but it is easier to remove it in post process then the inefficient use of look behinds here. Or if you don't mind the extra code we can use the capture group that exists here as well

```
Select-String "@([^\s]+)" -AllMatches | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches | 
      Select-Object Groups | 
      ForEach{$_.Groups[1]} | 
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Each matches object returned has 2 groups. The first is the entire capture and the first is our capture group.

If you wanted to be more critical for matches you could use `@([a-z1-9\.-]+)` which *I think* will only allow accepted domain characters (minus a couple of Unicode characters that are allowed in TLDs). If you filter out matches without periods then you would be set.

Answer (score 0):

Just match until the first dot after `@`:

```
(?ms)@([^.]+)
```

And by the way, your options don't make a lot of sense to me. Why do you need the `m` (multiline) and `s` (single line) options?

Comment: It's multiple email address in Outlook $msg.to. I tried to extract the domain in each email addresses so I can process it based the domain extracted. Thank you for your ideas and suggestion. But I still cannot get the domain out from email address that ends with multiple dot such as '.co.uk'